# In JavaScript, is there an easier way to check if a property of a property exists?

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining

Is there an easy way to natively determine if a deep property exists within an object in JavaScript?  For example, I need to access a property like this:

```
var myVal = appData.foo.bar.setting;
```

But there is a chance that either foo, foo.bar, or foo.bar.setting has not been defined yet. In Groovy, we can do something like this:

```
def myVal = appData?.foo?.bar?.setting
```

Is there a similar way to do this in JavaScript, without having to write a custom function or nested if statements?  I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571551/shorthand-function-for-checking-whether-a-property-exists) to be useful, but was hoping there was a more elegant and less custom way.

Comment: Outside of complying with the law of Demeter, no.

Comment: How I wish we had that operator in C#...

Comment: https://v8.dev/features/optional-chaining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) was introduced in ES2020. Now, you should be able to write:

```
const myVal = appData?.foo?.bar?.setting
```

Answer (score 16):

I find this very convenient:

```
var myVal = (myVal=appData) && (myVal=myVal.foo) && (myVal=myVal.bar) && myVal.settings;
```

If a property exists, the next part of the sequence will be attempted.

When the expression before `&&` evaluates to false, the next part of the expression will not be checked. If either of `myVal.appData.foo.bar.settings` is not defined, the value of `myVal` (`undefined`( will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Note that this approach is very useful for deeply nested variables. When the variable consists of two names, such as `foo.bar`, `myVal = foo && foo.bar` is more convenient.

Comment: There's no reason for those "sub-assignments" inside the parentheses.  JavaScript returns the actual value of the last expression of the sequence, or else `false`.  It does not coerce the values to boolean like other languages with similar short-circuiting operators.

Comment: @Pointy: the subassignments are to avoid repeating property names so that the overall code length is O(N) instead of O(N^2). I myself would try switching to a custom function by the time the length would start mattering though.

Comment: @Pointy `var myVal = appData && foo && bar && settings` won't produce the desired results. See my previous comment.

Comment: No, but I think pointy means: `var myVal = appData && appData.foo && appData.foo.bar && appData.foo.bar.settings;`.  If the var names are not long, I prefer that way, actually.  But if they are long, I prefer your way, Rob. Either way, I like it. +1

Comment: Ah I see what you mean; durrr.  OK it makes sense to me now (though I'm not sure I'd do it that way). Sorry for being blind and dense :-)

Comment: And it becomes absolutely unreadable and error-prone. Especially, when you encounter such construct for the first time.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, it's not great:

```
var myVal = appData && appData.foo && appData.foo.bar && appData.foo.bar.setting;
```

Another option:

```
try {
    var myVal = appData.foo.bar.setting;
} catch (e) {
    var myVal = undefined;
}
```

The . operator is not really intended for accessing objects like this. Probably using a function would be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I find other approaches a bit immense. So, what would be the major drawback of the following approach:

```
// Pass the path as a string, parse it, and try to traverse the chain.
Object.prototype.pathExists = function(path) {
    var members = path.split(".");
    var currentMember = this;

    for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        // Here we need to take special care of possible method 
        // calls and arrays, but I am too lazy to write it down.
        if (currentMember.hasOwnProperty(members[i])) {
            currentMember = currentMember[members[i]];   
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Basically, we define a method on the object (not necessarily) and that method takes the path  to a nested object and returns existence confirmation, like`appData.pathExists("foo.bar.setting");`

EDIT:
Check `object[prop] == undefined` is not semantically correct since it will return false even if the property is defined although its value is `undefined`; that is why I use `hasOwnProperty` to check is the property defined. This might not be important if one needs to just fetch the value.

Answer (score 2):

If, after:

```
var myVal = appData.foo && appData.foo.bar && appData.foo.bar.setting;
```

`myVal` is not `undefined`, it will hold the value of `appData.foo.bar.setting`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var x = {y:{z:{a:'b'}}}
x && x.y && x.y.z && x.y.z.a //returns 'b'
```

This is not as good as the groovy expression but it works. The evaluation stops after encountering the first undefined variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var product = ...,
    offering = (product||{}).offering,
    merchant = (offering||{}).merchant,
    merchantName = (merchant||{}).name;
if (merchantName)
   displayMerchantName(merchantName);
```

http://osteele.com/archives/2007/12/cheap-monads

Answer (score 0):

I just cooked this up so it might not work exactly right, I've also included two test cases.

```
function hasPropertyChain(o, properties) {

    var i = 0,
        currentPropertyChain = o;

    if(!o) {
        return false;
    }

    while(currentPropertyChain = currentPropertyChain[properties[i++]]);

    return i - 1 === properties.length;
}


alert(hasPropertyChain({a:{b:{c:'a'}}}, ['a','b','c'])); // true
alert(hasPropertyChain({a:{b:{c:'a'}}}, ['a','b','c', 'd'])); // false
```