# Javascript: How to verify the whole object path is defined?

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript test for existence of nested object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key)
>   [In JavaScript, is there an easier way to check if a property of a property exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636789/in-javascript-is-there-an-easier-way-to-check-if-a-property-of-a-property-exist)

I've been searching for an elegant way to verify if the entire object path is defined.

For example: `person.positions.values[0].company.name`
On every step of the way, after the `person`, it can be undefined.
Can this be done without actually going through them one by one?

Thank you.

Comment: The "proxy" feature proposed for next-generation JavaScript (probably) will make this possible (with a little work on the object definitions), but currently you're stuck with doing it yourself.

Comment: CoffeeScript has a nice construct for this: person.positions?.values[0]?.company?.name

Comment: ES2020 also allows the CoffeeScript style that Matt Stone mentions above.

For example: `const exists = obj1?.obj2?.obj3` etc. Prefix each dot with a question-mark and if any of the sub-objects are not present, the entire chain will return undefined.