# How to check if a multidimensional array item is set in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, isset

How to check if a multidimensional array item is set in JS?

```
w[1][2] = new Array;
w[1][2][1] = new Array;
w[1][2][1][1] = 10; w[1][2][1][2] = 20; w[1][2][1][4] = 30;
```

How to check if `w[1][2][1][3]` is set?

Solution with `if (typeof w[1][2][1][3] != 'undefined')` doesn't work.

I don't want to use an Object instead of Array.

Comment: what about `if (w[1][2][1][3] != 'undefined')` ?

Comment: that would check `w[1][2][1][3]` value is the text "undefined"

Comment: In what way does the `typeof` way not work?

Comment: @Patrick Evans, it returns error: TypeError: w[w1][w2][w3] is undefined in code: if (typeof w[w1][w2][w3][w4] != 'undefined') { return w[w1][w2][w3][w4]; }

Comment: then you need to check each previous array element for existence before checking the others.

Comment: @karthikr, returns the same error like with "typeof"

Comment: @Patrick Evans, thanks it works: if (typeof w[w1][w2][w3] != 'undefined' && typeof w[w1][w2][w3][w4] != 'undefined')

Comment: possible duplicate of [In JavaScript, is there an easier way to check if a property of a property exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636789/in-javascript-is-there-an-easier-way-to-check-if-a-property-of-a-property-exist)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not checking the previous array elements existence before checking its children as the children elements cant exist if the parent doesnt

```
if( 
    typeof(w) != 'undefined' &&
    typeof(w[1]) != 'undefined' &&
    typeof(w[1][2]) != 'undefined' &&
    typeof(w[1][2][1]) != 'undefined' &&
    typeof(w[1][2][1][3]) != 'undefined' &&
  ) {
    //do your code here if it exists  
  } else {
    //One of the array elements does not exist
  }
```

The if will run the code in the `else` clause if it sees any of the previous elements not existing. It stops checking the others if any of the preceding checks returns false.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a more generic way you can do it by extending the prototype of `Array`:

```
Array.prototype.check = function() {
    var arr = this, i, max_i;
    for (i = 0, max_i = arguments.length; i < max_i; i++) {
        arr = arr[arguments[i]];
        if (arr === undefined) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;    
}

w.check(1, 2, 1, 4); //will be true if w[1][2][1][4] exists
```

or if you don't like prototype extension you could use a separate function:

```
function check(arr) {
    var i, max_i;
    for (i = 1, max_i = arguments.length; i < max_i; i++) {
        arr = arr[arguments[i]];
        if (arr === undefined) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

check(w, 1, 2, 1, 4); //will be true if w[1][2][1][4] exists
```

Comment: I was unable to get your check function to work.  See my test code below.  I added a workaround below your 'check' that did work for me.