# How to check if array is multidimensional? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, multidimensional-array, response

I have two arrays of AJAX (JSON) response:

One dimension:

```
[["fili","Chif"],["Bart","deme"],["Bomb","Jyui"],["Joiu","FDPi"],["Doen","abcd"],["drog","MAIC"],["Jasi"
,"abcd"],["Jere","Jibi"]]
```

Three dimensions:

```
[[["5","#"],["2","N"],["L","7"],["C","8"],["F","W"],["K","T"],["Q","E"],["Z","\/"]],[["B","O"],["$","P"
],["1","Y"],["H","R"],["3","%"],["I","U"],["M","4"],["A","9"]],[["J","X"],["Bye","G"],["D","V"],["Bye"
,"6"]]]
```

I try to check if an array is multidimensional but does not work:

```
if (typeof arr[0][0] != "undefined" && arr[0][0].constructor == Array) {
     return true;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a multidimensional array item is set in JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883473/how-to-check-if-a-multidimensional-array-item-is-set-in-js)

Comment: Never use `==` or `!=` in Javascript. They're totally broken... go for `===` and `!==` instead.

Comment: Ok i will use ===, thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to check the first element of Array so use

```
if(arr[0].constructor === Array)
```

**DEMO**

```js
alert("[[]] returns " + ([[]].constructor === Array))
```

Comment: It worked when i changed to if(arr[0][0].constructor == Array) Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can also check all elements in the array so I think it would be more right way in **2019**

```js
const is2dArray = array =>  array.every(item => Array.isArray(item));
```

Comment: You surely mean `some` and not `every` dear sire. Also stating an arbitrary year in the answer is meaningless

Comment: @vsync since JS aint static typed, checking for multi dimensionality is always going to be dependent upon the type of input that might be provided to the function. Fortunately and mostly, we know the type of input that our function might encounter. Since, the question gives the input so all answers here are correct and checking first element is fastest. Plus, from question it looks like he would want every if he wants and not some otherwise his code might still fail

Comment: @bugwheels94 - it's a matter of the definition of what is a multidimensional array. Should all items be an Array or is it enough that one is. Also depends on the situation, and in OP's situation, it seems `some` would work better.

Answer (score 4):

If you like my answer, please vote for the person above me, but here is the above answer reconstructed in function format:

```
function is2dArray(array){
    if(array[0] === undefined){
        return false;
    }else{
        return (array[0].constructor === Array);
    }
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6zfzk56d/2)

Comment: So, you're saying arrow functions are not "functions enough"...?

Comment: (oh that answer wasn't there when I responded. I mean the top answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(array[0][0] === undefined){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

this one checks if the Array is a multi or just a normal array.

Comment: This only works if you're lucky enough to have the very first item as an array itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the constructor property, you may also use instanceof:

```
var arr = [];
var obj = {};

(arr instanceof Object)
// -> true

(obj instanceof Object)
// -> true

(arr instanceof Array)
// -> true

(obj instanceof Array)
// -> false
```