# One-liner to check if object and its method are both defined

Tags: javascript, undefined

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In javascript, test for property deeply nested in object graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343028/in-javascript-test-for-property-deeply-nested-in-object-graph)

I want to run this code block only and only if that obj.method1.mthod2 is true.
But It might be the case when obj itself is not defined. Or method1 is undefined.

```
if (obj.method1.method2) {

}
```

So am I supposed to do like that?

```
if (typeof(obj)!="undefined" && typeof(obj.method1)!="undefined" && typeof(obj.method1.method2)!="undefined" && obj.method1.method2) {

}
```

That looks ugly! Any way to do it shorter?
I have seen this [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript) link but it does not help.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses with `typeof`, because it is an operator not a function, so that saves you a character each time you use it. (E.g., `if (typeof obj!="undefined")`.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In javascript, test for property deeply nested in object graph?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343028/in-javascript-test-for-property-deeply-nested-in-object-graph) and [Shorthand function for checking whether a property exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571551/shorthand-function-for-checking-whether-a-property-exists) and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually write like this:

```
if (typeof(obj) != "undefined" && obj.method1 && obj.method1.method2){
    // The magic
}
```

I mostly do this with functions though, since I'm pretty sure some instances of primitive types would evaluate to false, even though they are not undefined.

edit: As **lanzz** points out in the comment, obj needs a typeof.

Comment: Referencing undefined `obj` throws `ReferenceError: obj is not defined` in Chrome.

Comment: Good. At least only one typeof per IF statement :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be typeof(obj) **!==** "undefined"?

Answer (score 0):

try `try`

```
try {
    if(obj.method1.method2) {
         alert("ok!");
    }
}catch(e) {
    alert("obj or some property not defined");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More succinctly :

```
  if (obj && obj.method1 && obj.method1.method2) {
    ...
  }
```